# Is there any way to auto restart after crashing in github workflows

Tags: python, telegram, github-actions

```
Deleting original file NF - PAID MY DUES - youtube-LLAgke7QprM.f140.m4a (pass -k to keep)
/home/runner/work/_temp/9708cc07-bf79-4478-beda-081cae98f143.sh: line 3:  3270 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 nani.py
Error: Process completed with exit code 139.
```

I'm trying to host my python bot on git workflows. 
It will play music (in Telegram voice chat). 
But it keeps crashing after some time.

*Is there any way to automatically restart a workflow after any error?*

Github repository to check the workflow implementation : https://github.com/Nksama/workflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For what I know there is no way to restart a workflow automatically through configurations yet...*

However, there are different ways to achieve a similar result using workflows implementation with Github Actions. It won't be exactly a restart, as the workaround would be to start the workflow again if it fails.

---

**The first option** could be to use another workflow with the [workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) trigger to check if the first workflow ran successfully, and if not, send a dispatch event to run it again (in that case, you would have to add a [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) trigger to the first workflow).

---

**Another option** could be to add 2 steps at the end of your first job (build) to save the job status as an artifact.

```yaml
      - name: Create file status_job1.txt and write the job status into it
        if: always()
        run: echo ${{ job.status }} > status_job1.txt
      - name: Upload file status_job1.txt as an artifact
        if: always()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job1
          path: status_job1.txt
```

Then, a second job would always check the output of the first one:

```yaml
  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job1]
    if: always()
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact pass_status_job1
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job1
      - name: Set the status of Job 1, as output parameter
        id: set_outputs
        run: echo "::set-output name=status_job1::$(<pass_status_job1/status_job1.txt)"
      - name: Show the values of the output
        run: |
          # using the syntax steps.<step_id>.outputs.<output_name> to access the output parameter
          echo "status_job1 = ${{ steps.set_outputs.outputs.status_job1 }}"
          # other steps or commands to perform an operation according to its value.
          [...]
```

For example, at the end of `job2`, you could send a `dispatch event` to the same workflow if the status of the job1 is failure (in that case, you would have to add a [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) trigger to the workflow as well) to start the workflow again (as I explained, it won't be exactly a restart as this will create a new workflow run).

---

Here is an [action to create a repository dispatch event](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/repository-dispatch), or you can do it directly calling [the Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)

Answer (score 0):

As much as there's no way to set it with a single workflow, maybe it's possible to set up another task that will do the same thing as our [lambda](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/33948a150fefe36ebf82bb8196b52215e577270b/tests/ci/workflow_approve_rerun_lambda/app.py#L261-L276)

We receive the `workflow_run` event from GH webhooks and process it. So, the given function checks that the workflow has only `failed` and `success` statuses. In the case of a dead runner, when a spot instance was terminated, we [restart](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/33948a150fefe36ebf82bb8196b52215e577270b/tests/ci/workflow_approve_rerun_lambda/app.py#L282) failed jobs.

I feel it could be a job, that is triggered [on: workflow_run: types: [completed]](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run).

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    types:
      - completed
```